# "xacro: in-order processing became default in ROS Melodic. You can drop the option" error

Tags: ros

https://github.com/EuropeanRoverChallenge/ERC-Remote-Maintenance-Sim

Using the link I wrote all commands which is given in "Install on the host system" section.

When I try this commend:

```
$ roslaunch ur3_sim simulation.launch
```

It gives error like this:

```
> ... logging to /home/ubuntu4/.ros/log/f2319ee2-b808-11ed-bb34-1be4f5885cab/roslaunch-ubuntu4-6223.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
xacro: in-order processing became default in ROS Melodic. You can drop the option.
No such file or directory: /home/ubuntu4/catkin_ws3/src/universal_robot/ur_description/urdf/common.gazebo.xacro [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ubuntu4/catkin_ws3/src/universal_robot/ur_description/urdf/common.gazebo.xacro'
when processing file: /home/ubuntu4/catkin_ws3/src/UR3_sim/ur3_sim_description/urdf/ur3_sim.urdf.xacro
RLException: while processing /home/ubuntu4/catkin_ws3/src/UR3_sim/ur3_sim_gazebo/launch/ur3_sim.launch:
while processing /home/ubuntu4/catkin_ws3/src/UR3_sim/ur3_sim_description/launch/ur3_sim_upload.launch:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [['/opt/ros/noetic/lib/xacro/xacro', '--inorder', '/home/ubuntu4/catkin_ws3/src/UR3_sim/ur3_sim_description/urdf/ur3_sim.urdf.xacro', 'transmission_hw_interface:=hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface']] returned with code [2]. 
Param xml is <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find ur3_sim_description)/urdf/ur3_sim.urdf.xacro' transmission_hw_interface:=$(arg transmission_hw_interface)"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I think this is your actual error: `No such file or directory: '/home/ubuntu4/catkin_ws3/src/universal_robot/ur_description/urdf/common.gazebo.xacro'`

Comment: @ignacio I will edit the title, thanks. Do you know what the solution is?

Comment: You need to check if that file exists

Comment: To find the exact solution, you need to add the contents of the simulation.launch file so we can see what exactly you are tring to launch and from where. In the error that is shown above, either the file is missing, otherwise the path that it is searching for the file at is incorrect and needs to be edited